# best solution to overcome threading issue on shared object

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Using Task Parallel Library in .net 4.0, I want to know what is the best solution to this situation :

My code is starting a task that do a lot of long running steps (steps need to be done one after other). 
I have an object Result that aggregate the result of each steps. 
The result object is modified in the task ( so in the thread related to this task ). 
I also have an web service where we can fetch the current Result object to see the progress of the task. 
So the Result object is a share object between the task and the main thread of my code. What is the best approach to implement this to be sure I don't have threading issues and things like that ?

Here a sample of what i'm talking about. Just note that _doWork would not be a static like in the code, it will be a member in another class higher in the hierarchy.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Step1Result
    {
    }

    public class Step2Result
    {
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public Step1Result Step1Result;
        public Step2Result Step2Result;
    }

    class DoWork
    {
        public Result Result;

        public DoWork()
        {
            Result = new Result();
        }

        public void Process()
        {
            // Execute Step 1
            Result.Step1Result = Step1();
            Result.Step2Result = Step2();

            // Other Steps ( long - running )
        }

        public Step1Result Step1()
        {
            // Long running step that can takes minutes

            return new Step1Result();
        }

        public Step2Result Step2()
        {
            // Long running step that can takes minutes

            return new Step2Result();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        private static DoWork _doWork;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _doWork = new DoWork();

            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _doWork.Process());
            task.Wait();
        }

        // This method will be called from a web service at anytime.
        static Result CalledFromWebService()
        {
            return _doWork.Result;
        }
    }
}
```

The trouble here is accessing _doWork.Result from both the Task and the Main thread. True ? What could be done to overcome this ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Your real problem is that you haven't modeled a service request properly.  Once you actually implement it, you'll find that the request already runs on a worker thread.  No need to start your own thread, no need to use a global variable.  Just call Process and return Result.

Comment: Hans - Just to be clear, the Process part will not be done inside the web service call. The web service call will just check the current result values and return it to the call. You are correct when saying that the web service call will run in is own thread. The Process part will be done inside a 'main task' in a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

I would change DoWork.Result property to GetCurrentResult() method and return each time a new copy of current operation result (you can copy object using [MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). I dont see any need to share the same object.

Additionalty, I would use ReadWriteLockSlim. So DoWork class will look like this

```
class DoWork
{
    private readonly Result _result;
    private readonly ReadWriteLockSlim _lock = new ReadWriteLockSlim();

    public DoWork()
    {
        _result = new Result();
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        // Execute Step 1
        Step1Result st1result = Step1();
        try
        {
             _lock.EnterWriteLock();
             _result.Step1Result = st1result;
        }
        finally
        {
             _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }

        Step2Result st2result = Step2();
         try
        {
             _lock.EnterWriteLock();
             _result.Step2Result = st2result;
        }
        finally
        {
             _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }

        // Other Steps ( long - running )
    }

    public Step1Result Step1()
    {
        // Long running step that can takes minutes

        return new Step1Result();
    }

    public Step2Result Step2()
    {
        // Long running step that can takes minutes

        return new Step2Result();
    }

    public Result GetCurrentResult()
    {
        try
        {
             _lock.EnterReadLock();
             return (Result)_result.MemberwiseCopy();
        }
        finally
        {
             _lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly you don't have thread safety issues accessing the Result object.

As you say the steps have to be finished one after each other so you won't be able to run them concurrently.
So inside `Process()` you can start Step1 in a task, then `.Continue` with Step2 in another task etc

Therefore you have a single writer thread and no concurrency issues. In this scenario it doesn't matter if you have another thread accessing the
result if that's a read-only fetching thread

You would only need a concurrent collection like ConcurrentDictionary to store the result if you were accessing a collection from different threads.

You would only need a ReadWriteLockSlim if the steps are not run one after each other and you had more than one writer

Comment: TonyS - You seem to understand correctly my concerns. In the Process() method I will not start any new tasks, I will just call each step one after others ( with some more business logics ). So all step will be run in the same task ( the one created in the main in this case ). So your explanation say that if I have only one writer ( which is my case ), and one reader, I do not need any thread safety mechanism ? Do I understand this correctly ? I must admit that your answer is contrasting a lot with Garf1eld answer below.

Comment: I think so. Your problem doesn't require synchronization between the writer and the reader. It doesn't really matter when the reader executes because it doesn't alter the state. Also you are fetching so it will executed soon afterwards so indeed it doesn't seem to need synchronization. Your only issue may be to know if the stepresult is valid, for this I would understand that if the Step1Result is null then step1 hasn't completed yet

Answer (score 0):

Your only concern here is dirty reads of the `Result` object returned from `CalledFromWebService`. You could add boolean properties to your `Result` object and remove the need for locks like so:

```
public class Result
{
    public volatile bool IsStep1Valid;
    public Step1Result Step1Result;

    public volatile bool IsStep2Valid;
    public Step2Result Step2Result;
}
```

Assignment to boolean values are atomic, so you don't have to worry about dirty reads and writes. You could then use those boolean values in your `Process` method like so:

```
public void Process()
{
    // Execute Step 1
    Result.Step1Result = Step1();
    Result.IsStep1Valid = true;


    Result.Step2Result = Step2();
    Result.IsStep2Valid = true;

    // Other Steps ( long - running )
}
```

Notice that the assignment to `IsStep1Valid` is after the assignment to `Step1Result` this ensures that `Step1Result` has a value assigned to it from the Task before `IsStep1Valid` is set to true.

Now when you access the result in your main thread by calling `CalledFromWebService` you can simply do the following:

```
void MyCode() {
    var result = Program.CalledFromWebService();
    if (result.IsStep1Valid) {
         // do stuff with result.Step1Result
    } else {
        // if need be notify the user that step 1 is not complete yet
    }
    if (result.IsStep2Valid) {
         // do stuff with result.Step2Result
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Checking the value of `IsStep1Valid` before you try to access the `Step1Result` property ensures that you are not getting a dirty read of the `Step1Result` property.

**Update:** A separate web service will not have access to the result object in the windows service because they run in separate app domains. You will need to expose a web service from inside your windows service, and have the main thread of the windows service load the web service and call your background task. You don't have to publicly expose this web service. You can still host a web service in IIS or where ever you originally intended. It would simply call the web service hosted by the windows service.

Comment: You need to mark the "Valid" bools as `volatile` otherwise the compiler could "optimize" the code and make the assignment of `true` happen before the result is populated.

Comment: I will probably have to create the Step1Result before ending the Step1 actually ( to show the progress of the step will the step is doing is job). So I could new Step1Result member in the constructor of Result to that is it always existing. Probably add somes member to Step1Result like progress indicator that will be update from the step method. Good ?

Comment: Charles - Also, to be clear, CalledFromWebService will not be call from my main thread, but will be called from the implementation of my web service.

Comment: @Hockeymtl - will the web service be the owner of the background thread?

Comment: @Charles The web service will not be the owner of the background thread. This will be run in a windows service. The windows service start a first long running task that will trigger the code that we can see in my main here.